# How to join 2 tables without common fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 2 tables:

Table 1: **first_names**

```
id | first_name 
 1 | Joey 
 7 | Ross
 17| Chandler
```

Table 2: **last_names**

```
id | first_name
 2 | Tribbiani
 7 | Geller 
 25| Bing
```

**Desired result:**

```
id | full_name
1  | Joey Tribbiani
2  | Ross Geller
3  | Chandler Bing
```

Task:
**Write the solution using only the simplest SQL syntax.**  Using store procedures, declaring variables, `ROW_NUMBER()`, `RANK()` functions are forbidden.

I have solution using `ROW_NUMBER()` function, but no ideas about solving this task using only the simplest SQL syntax.

P.S. I'm only trainee and it's my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: *"Write the solution WITHOUT using store procedures, T-SQL and ROW_NUMBER() function"* Why? Why can't use you `ROW_NUMBER`? (And why is the data no malformed?)

Comment: Also, your latest update really changes the scope of the question with those new values for id.

Comment: is it allowed to use `rank` or `dense_rank` :) ?

Comment: Is `row_number()` the only fobidden function? What about `rank()`?

Comment: I just noticed that the OP says they need to do this  without using T-SQL. If they can't use T-SQL, they can't use SQL Server for this; every statement you use to query SQL Server will be a T-SQL Statement; that's the SQL Dialect you use to query SQL Server. Is PL\SQL acceptable and you can use Oracle?

Comment: I received this task a few days ago on interview. I solved this task using `ROW_NUMBER()` function, but the new question was "Solve this task without using using `ROW_NUMBER()`. You can use only the simplest SQL syntax. Declaration of variables, `RANK()` function are also forbidden."

Comment: In my view, the simplest syntax *is* using `ROW_NUMBER`. Using other functions just makes it more confusing to understand, not easier.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Probably an interviewer would like to discover the level of my algorithmic thinking or ability for searching not usual solutions.

Comment: I *assume* that things like `LEAD` are off the table too then. Personally, I think that the only person that can answer this is the interviewer, and any answer they give will not be as simple as `ROW_NUMBER`; this very much sounds like a non-question. Perhaps they were expecting you to challenge them on it, or ask "Why can't you use `ROW_NUMBER`? Are you using SQL Server 2000? If so, why are you using out of support technology, which is a security concern?". Those would be my questions at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create an id to join the tables. 
This can be the order number in the table based in ids:

```
select 
  f.counter id, concat(f.first_name, ' ', l.last_name) full_name
from (
  select t.*, (select count(*) from first_names where id < t.id) + 1 counter
  from first_names t
) f inner join (
 select t.*, (select count(*) from last_names where id < t.id) + 1 counter
  from last_names t
) l
on l.counter = f.counter
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=60308913ffb157e001f467e6fd402f82).
Results:

```
> id | full_name     
> -: | :-------------
>  1 | Joey Tribbiani
>  2 | Ross Geller   
>  3 | Chandler Bing
```

Comment: Why use a triangular join and not a Window function here?

Comment: Window function? The requirement is keep things as simple as possible. This is how I understand: *WITHOUT using store procedures, T-SQL and ROW_NUMBER() function*

Comment: "This can be the order number in the table based in ids", which is in fact nothing else than a Rownumber...

Comment: It is not *ROW_NUMBER() function*

Comment: I didn't say `ROW_NUMBER` , Forpas. What's wrong with `COUNT(id) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`? It does exactly what `ROW_NUMBER` does, but isn't `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @larnu looks like the task is to emulate ROW_NUMBER()  etc with sqlserver 2000 :)

Comment: If the OP *is* using SQL Sevrer 2000, @Serg , they should be tagging that, and then explaining why they're using technology that has been out of support for about decade. :)

Comment: @Larnu This has to be a school assignment. The requirements are placed for a reason. Who knows about the level and the purpose of the assignment ?

Comment: If it *is* a school requirement then this is actually off-topic without the OP showing their attempts and research; as they need to show them as per the Asking page guidelines. We all know that the users on StackOverflow won't learn anything if the volunteers do their homework for them. :)

Comment: All these conditions apply to non school assignments too, right?

Answer (score 2):

Simple `join` will suffice here

```
select * from first_names fn
join last_names ln on fn.id = ln.id - 1
```

But your question is very unclear though. Because `join` here is based rather on knowledge about Friends series rather than concrete logic...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is a stupid solution; it's vastly inefficient to `ROW_NUMBER`, and I wouldn't be surprised if `LEAD` is "not allowed" as `ROW_NUMBER` isn't.  The fact that you were told to "use the simpliest SQL" means that the SQL you want to use is a subquery/CTE and `ROW_NUMBER`; that is as simple as this can really go. Anything else add a layer on unneeded complexity and will likely just make the query suffer from performance degradation. This one, for example, means you need to scan both tables twice; where as with `ROW_NUMBER` it would be once.

```
CREATE TABLE FirstNames (id int, FirstName varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE LastNames (id int, LastName varchar(10));

INSERT INTO FirstNames
VALUES(1,'Joey'),
      (7,'Ross'),
      (17,'Chandler');

INSERT INTO LastNames
VALUES (2,'Tribbiani'),
       (7,'Geller'),
       (25,'Bing');
GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT FN.id,
           FN.FirstName,
           LN.LastName
    FROM FirstNames FN
        LEFT JOIN LastNames LN ON FN.id = LN.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LN.id,
           FN.FirstName,
           LN.LastName
    FROM LastNames LN
        LEFT JOIN FirstNames FN ON LN.id = FN.id
    WHERE FN.id IS NULL),
FullNames AS(
    SELECT C.id,
        C.FirstName,
        ISNULL(C.LastName, LEAD(C.LastName) OVER (ORDER BY id)) AS LastName
    FROM CTE C)
SELECT *
FROM FullNames FN
WHERE FN.FirstName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FN.id;


GO

DROP TABLE FirstNames;
DROP TABLE LastNames;
```

To answer the "Task" given:
"Task: Write the solution using only the simplest SQL syntax. Using store procedures, declaring variables, ROW_NUMBER(), RANK() functions are forbidden."

My answer would be the below?

*"Why is this a requirement? SQL Server has supported `ROW_NUMBER` for 14 years, since SQL Server 2005. If you can't use `ROW_NUMBER` this infers you're using SQL Server 2000. This is actually a big security problem for the company, as 2000 has been out of support for close to a decade. Legislation like GDPR require a company to keep the technology they use secure, and it is very unlikely that this is therefore being met.*

*If this is the case, the solution if not the find a way around using `ROW_NUMBER` but to get the company back up to do date. The latest version of SQL Server that you can upgrade to from SQL Server 2000 is 2008; which also runs out of support on July 16 of this year. We'll need to get an instance up and running and get the existing features into this new server ASAP and get QA testing done as soon as possible. This needs to be the highest priority thing. After that we need to repeat the cycle to another version of SQL Server. The latest is 2017, which does support migration from 2008.*

*Once we've done that, we can then actually make use of `ROW_NUMBER` in the query; providing the simplest solution and also bringing the company back into a secure environment."*

Sometimes requirements need to be challenged. From experience management can make some "stupid" requirements, because they don't understand the technology. When you're in an IT role, sometimes you will need to question those requirements and explain why the requirement isn't actually a good idea. Then, instead, you can aid Management to find the correct solution for the problem. At the end of the day, what they might be trying to fix could be an XY problem; and part of your troubleshooting will be to find out what X really is.

Comment: What is this? Not only that it does not meet the requirement: *You can use only the simplest SQL syntax*, but it also gives wrong results for the id. It should be 1, 2, 3

Comment: @forpas my point is that `ROW_NUMBER` **is** the simplest solution (My answer even starts off with *"Honestly, this is a stupid solution"*). Even yours, with `COUNT` is not "simple". And yes, it won't give the correct `id` values because you can't use `ROW_NUMBER`. The problem isn't the answer here, as such, it's the question. Like I said in the comments, the OP actually says "Without using T-SQL"; making this impossible to do on SQL Server. It would be like being asked to write a C# application without using C#.

Comment: The OP explained what it is all about: *You can use only the simplest SQL syntax* and *without ROW_NUMBER*. Your answer is out of everything about the requirement. So why did you post it? My answer would be inefficient **if** the restrictions were not there. But they are, so it is the simpler solution because it is the only solution that meets the requirement and gives the correct result.

Comment: Considering the OP has also said that `RANK` is off the table @forpas it's very likely so is `COUNT`; hence my comment about `LEAD` being off the table too. The only person that can answer this is the interviewer who asked the OP, as the question really makes no sense; especially, again, when they told the OP they can't use T-SQL.

Comment: COUNT is simple and you understand what *You can use only the simplest SQL syntax* means.

Comment: And so is `ROW_NUMBER` @forpas. [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=61dc124b97aeea64c1886044317ab32f) is simpler than [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5c2b9a42ee133e6235a679e0dbff292d), and is why the question makes no sense. Why use 2 scans of each table when you could do 1? Why use a triangular `JOIN`, which can ruin performance? Why reinvent the wheel for `ROW_NUMBER` when it's been in SQL Server for 14 years? These are questions only the interviewer can answer, and the answer to "make the query simpler" is the use `ROW_NUMBER` as it **is** simple.

Comment: Because this is the requirement.

Comment: Which leads us back to "Why is it is requirement?". We all know from experience that management make up requirements because they know nothing about IT, and it's been our roles to argue those requirements, because, at the end of the day, the requirement is stupid. This feels like it's one of those times.

Comment: No it does not lead us there. The OP explained that all this is an interview assignment. Nothing more.

Comment: Then my answer is, "It's time to upgrade off SQL Server 2000" @forpas :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with versions and upgrading. It's an assignment in an interview.

Comment: Looks like we're at an impasse here, @forpas, but my conclusion is that the interviewer was testing the OP to see if they would question odd requirements. That is a something that they do, as it show that the interviewee isn't afraid to question things when they have the expertise to. Thanks for the conversation anyway, hope you enjoy the rest of your weekend.